# Get output in a specific format

Tags: go

I write a go code that filters data containing id, name, and age. It is printed to the terminal only if the age in the data is under 21. I'm used slice of struct and for loop to get the result. Here is the code:

```
type data struct {
    id   int
    name string
    age  int
}

func FilterData() {
    var people = []data{
        {id: 1, name: "Udin", age: 12},
        {id: 2, name: "Wati", age: 51},
        {id: 3, name: "Budi", age: 34},
        {id: 4, name: "Agus", age: 16},
        {id: 5, name: "Sari", age: 19},
        {id: 6, name: "Ririn", age: 21},
    }

    var result = []data{}

    for _, item := range people {
        if item.age < 21 {
            result = append(result, item)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
}

func main() {
    FilterData()
}
```

It gives output like this:

```
[{id:1 name:Udin age:12} {id:4 name:Agus age:16} {id:5 name:Sari age:19}]
```

I need to get an output in the format:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Udin', age: 12 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Agus', age: 16 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Sari', age: 19 },
]
```

Is there a way to get the desired format output?

Comment: Yes, for example you could output each line separately in a loop. Did you try that? What went wrong?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes I did try it, but it doesn't have those brackets at the beginning and the end of the output

Comment: That looks very close to JSON, but its missing the quotes around the keys. Do you want JSON?

Comment: @Schwern no, i don't want JSON

Comment: @purplehippo If it's not a standard format, you'll either have to find a pretty printer library that is configurable enough to produce that format, or write your own.

Comment: @purplehippo fmt.Println(“[“) before the loop and fmt.Println(“]”) after the loop suggested by mkreiger.

Answer (score 1):

Here is basic implementation.

```
package main

import(
  "fmt"
)

type data struct {
    id   int
    name string
    age  int
}

func print_data_array(datum []data) {
  fmt.Println("[")
  for _, data := range(datum) {
    fmt.Printf("  %v,\n", format_data_struct(data))
  }
  fmt.Println("]")
}

func format_data_struct(d data) (string) {
  // Note: this does not escape quotes in d.name.
  return fmt.Sprintf(
    `{ %v: %v, %v: "%v", %v: %v }`,
    "id", d.id,
    "name", d.name,
    "age", d.age,
  )
}

func main() {
  var people = []data{
      {id: 1, name: "Udin", age: 12},
      {id: 2, name: "Wati", age: 51},
      {id: 3, name: "Budi", age: 34},
      {id: 4, name: "Agus", age: 16},
      {id: 5, name: "Sari", age: 19},
      {id: 6, name: "Ririn", age: 21},
  }

  print_data_array(people)
}
```